# Display multiple window in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, multi-window

Simple question but can't find the answer, am looking for a module that allows me to display in one window multiple windows with python.
Example Above:
 
[![Example][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8zzD.png

Comment: Like this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_multiple_document_interface.htm ?

Comment: Yes, thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can have a idea to do this From here. Kivy can be used for the purpose [Check this too.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Prt_SKkZji8&ab_channel=Codemy.com)